# Loading spinner VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, spinner, loading

I have to make a loading animation when a client clicks the button search to popup a spinner animation, in order the client can't click multiple times on the search button. However, I don't know how to call this animation. I have made this until now:

***table.vue:***

```
<div id="overlay-back"></div>
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="dvLoading">
     <img id="loading-image" src="../assets/images/spinner.gif" alt="Loading..."/>
  </div>
</div>

      loadData(filter) {
        var self = this;
        const url = this.$session.get('apiUrl') + 'loadSystemList'
        this.submit('post', url, filter);
      }
```

***main.css:***

```
#overlay {
  position : absolute;
  top      : 0;
  left     : 0;
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
  z-index  : 995;
  display  : none;
}

#overlay-back {
  position   : absolute;
  top        : 0;
  left       : 0;
  width      : 100%;
  height     : 100%;
  background : #000;
  opacity    : 0.6;
  filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
  z-index    : 990;
  display    : none;
}

#dvLoading {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -125px 0 0 -125px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

I need to call the animation when the button Search is clicked and invokes the function loadData. I would be happy if you help me guys :) I am kinda lost

***Update1:***

file.vue:

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <div id="dvLoading">
          <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-10x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="toolbarStrip">
          <br><h1 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 10px;">System table</h1>
          <fieldset class="buttons">
            <span class="logInBTN" v-on:click="loadData(filter)" id="loadData">Search</span>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      import config from '../main.js'

      var loadButton = document.getElementById("loadData");

      export default {

        data(){
          return {

        },

        methods: {

          stopShowingLoading(){

            var element = document.getElementById("dvLoading");
            element.classList.remove("showloading");
            var button = document.getElementById("loadData");
            button.classList.remove("showloading");

          },

          loadData(filter) {
            var element = document.getElementById("dvLoading");
            element.classList.add("showloading");
            var button = document.getElementById("loadData");
            button.classList.add("showloading");

            var self = this;
            const url = this.$session.get('apiUrl') + 'loadSystemList'
            this.submit('post', url, filter);

            window.setTimeout(function(){stopShowingLoading();},3000);
          },

          submit(requestType, url, submitData) {
            this.$http[requestType](url, submitData)
              .then(response => {
              this.items = response.data;
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log('error:' + error);
          });
          },

          newData: function(){
            config.router.push('/systemData')
          }
        }
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, whilst I *have* done things with vue.js in the past, I've forgotten much of that so there may be a better way within that framework than this, which is a vanilla JS approach really...

You don't seem to have a requirement to *stop* showing the loading animation.  When I've done this sort of thing in the past, I've usually made use of callbacks to know when the loading operation is complete, and at that point 'turn off' the loading animation.  I've included a function to hide the loading, but don't know where/if you'd want to call this.

This is untested, so apologies for typos or other minor errors...

css:

```
/* 
Override the  display:none on the #dvloading element if it has a class
of 'showloading 
*/
#dvLoading.showloading{
    display:block 
}
```

JS:

```
function loadData(filter) {

    /*
      Add the 'showloading' class to the #dvLoading element.
      this should make it appear due to the css change...
    */
    var element = document.getElementById("dvLoading");
    element.classList.add("showloading");

    var self = this;
    const url = this.$session.get('apiUrl') + 'loadSystemList'
    this.submit('post', url, filter);
}

function stopShowingLoading(){
    /* 
       When loading finishes, reverse the process
    */
    var element = document.getElementById("dvLoading");
    element.classList.remove("showloading");
}
```

edit: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23mcqkzs/) to show general approach

further edit:  To stop showing animation only after data has loaded (I just used a timeout to simulate this in my example) then you need to simply stop it after the data has loaded, which would be something like this:

```
submit(requestType, url, submitData) {
   this.$http[requestType](url, submitData)
   .then(response => {
      // We've received the data now, so set items and
      //also hide the loading animation.
      this.items = response.data;
      this.stopShowingLoading(); 
  })
...
```

and then remove the `window.setTimeout()` call altogether.

Comment: Well, its not working for me. Maybe I am not doing something correct I am not sure. If there is somebody else who can help too.

Comment: I suspect there's some issue with the overlay stuff...  I've put together a very simple example jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/23mcqkzs/

Comment: In that, I've removed most of the overlay stuff, and it just uses a button with a timer to simulate a long-running task (3 seconds).  it uses CSS to show/hide the button and the spinner, and JS to simply add/remove classes when 'busy' and 'finished'.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I updated my first post, it doesn't dissappear the loading animation.

Comment: I get that stopShowingLoading() is not defined

Comment: Ok, i accepted your answer :) Thanks for the help. However, I have one more question is it possible to "dynamically" set the the for setTimeout. So that when you click the button search, it loads data in a table. When its finished loading then stop the animation?

Comment: don't use the timeout - stop the animation after the data has loaded (in the .then() code of your submit() method... I'll edit my answer to show what I mean as you can't format code in comments well...

Comment: @Decrux, I've added to my post explaining this.  basically remove the setTimeout() call altogether and remove the loading once the data is available.  It's probably a good idea to also remove it if you get an error, OR if there is a timeout for other reasons (though this should eventually cause an error response anyway).